# PHP Wait For Image Upload to Finish Before Resizing

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading

Is there a way to "pause" php to wait for a file to upload before manipulating it?

I am using this to upload photos:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$PhotoField]["tmp_name"], $BrandDirectory . "/" . $NewPhotoName);
```

That part seems to be working well. The issue is that after that I am resizing the photo that is uploaded using:

```
$image = new SimpleImage();
$image->load($BrandDirectory . "/" . $NewPhotoName);
$image->resizeToWidth(1024);
$image->save($BrandDirectory . "/" . $NewPhotoName);
```

That part seems to work as well to, as long as the photo has finished uploading. 
So, it seems that I need some way for everything to wait before the upload finishes.

Comment: what is the problem in this procedure?

Comment: you cant move a file until its finished uploading

Comment: Your PHP won't kick off until the file is uploaded.

Comment: What do you mean? You PHP only executes *after* the image has finished uploading.

Comment: put if(move_uploaded_file((-----)){}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$PhotoField]["tmp_name"], $BrandDirectory . "/" . $NewPhotoName)){

$image = new SimpleImage();
$image->load($BrandDirectory . "/" . $NewPhotoName);
$image->resizeToWidth(1024);
$image->save($BrandDirectory . "/" . $NewPhotoName);

}
```